# For loop not "refreshing" Python

Tags: python, loops

I am running a rock paper scissors lizard Spock game in Python.  I want it to play 5 rounds with different bots.  The problem I am having is that when I try to loop the rounds in my main function is just prints out the same match 5 times even if the bot picks its move at random.

The for loop:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    p1move = p1.play()
    p2move = p2.play()
    print(p1move.compareTo(p2move))
```

The play method:

```
class Human(Player):
    if decisionint == 1:
       def play(hum1):
           hum1 = Rock
           return hum1
```

Example of a Bot:

```
class RandomBot(Player):
num = randint(1, 5)
if num == 1:
    def play(rando1):
        rando1 = Rock
        return rando1
else:
    if num == 2:
        def play(rando2):
            rando2 = Paper
            return rando2
```

Rock class:

```
class Rock(Element):
def compareTo(_name):
    if _name == Lizard:
        global p1wins
        p1wins += 1
        print("Rock crushes Lizard, Win")
```

The main method asks who you want the two players to be and then sets your first choice to `p1` and your second choice to `p2`

If you need any more code let me know.  I think this should be enough but I am not positive.
Thanks

Comment: apparently p2 is the same throughout the loop, and it's play method is constant (though randomly generated at instanciation time), so it makes sense that all 5 outputs are identical

Comment: You need to call `random.seed()` otherwise you'll get the same `randint` every time

Comment: ^ thank you, as I am still new to Python I thought the randint would just make a new int every time

Comment: It would if it was an instance attribute in `__init__`, rather than a class attribute. Indeed, all of your classes have the same problem.

Comment: No, @Cyber, randint does generate a new random int every time.  Or at least it does for me without calling random.seed()

Comment: @d_rez90 I'm sorry you are correct, I was mixing up C++'s `rand()` function which needs to be seeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your play methods, you're assigning Rock to instance name, and then returning it, but basically equivalent to:

```
class Human(Player):
    if decisionint == 1:
       def play(self):
           return Rock
```

If you want this to vary so you can properly model it, you need to return a random choice of element every time.

e.g. near the top of your code:

```
import random

CHOICES = (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock)
```

And in your `play` method:

```
return random.choice(CHOICES)
```

Comment: The first one you had worked flawlessly, is the edit more efficient/just better programming or is the first one fine?

Comment: @Kooky_Lukey It means less code repetition, because your human and bot players will need both, right? I'm also trying to emphasize good style, because the list of choices is a constant, and can live at the module level.

Answer (score 1):

Although I love that you're using objects here, I think you can be doing more with inheritance than you are, and abusing DRY further. Try this:

```
import random

class Selection(object):
    def __init__(self, value, wins_against, name=None):
        self.value = value
        self.wins_against = wins_against
        self.name = name
    def compare(self,other):
        if other.value == self.value: return 0
        elif other.value in self.wins_against: return 1
        else: return -1

Rock = Selection(0, (2,3), "Rock")         # beats scissors+lizard
Paper = Selection(1, (0,4), "Paper")       # beats rock+spock
Scissors = Selection(2, (1,3), "Scissors") # beats paper+lizard
Lizard = Selection(3, (1,4), "Lizard")     # beats paper+spock
Spock = Selection(4, (0,2), "Spock")       # beats rock+scissors

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.choice = None
        if name is None: self.name = "Computer"
        else: self.name = name
    def choose(self):
        self.choice = random.choice([Rock,Paper,Scissors,Lizard,Spock])
    def compare(self,other):
        """1 = win, 0 = tie, -1 = lose"""
        return self.choice.compare(other.choice)

class Human(Player):
    def choose(self):
        self.choice = None
        while self.choice is None:
            print("""1. Rock
2. Paper
3. Scissors
4. Lizard
5. Spock""")
            in_ = input(">> ")
            try:
                self.choice = {"1":Rock,"2":Paper,"3":Scissors,"4":Lizard,"5":Spock}[in_]
            except KeyError:
                pass

def play(player1,player2):
    for player in (player1,player2):
        player.choose()
    print("{} vs {}".format(player1.choice.name,player2.choice.name))
    result = player1.compare(player2)
    if result:
        print("{0.name} wins!".format(
            player1 if result > 0 else player2)) 
    else:
        print("Tie game!")
    print("\n\n")


Player1 = Human("Joe Schmoe")
Player2 = Player() # bot

for _ in range(5):
    play(Player1,Player2)
```